# nestjs - return db object from guard

Tags: authentication, nestjs, nest, interceptor, guard

what is the best practice for having a db responsce after guard validtion

1- during guard validation im check if the user is in the db do here i would like to return the user in whole controllers

how do I get the user the controller?

the solution i found is to set request.user
and get id as a body params but i dont like it

there is a better way ?
i need to do that almos in all controllers

here is my guard

```
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    try {
      const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      const key = this.extractAuthFromRequest(request);
      const data = await this.authService.getFromDb(key);
      request.data = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common practice, to set a new property on the request object and access it later with `request.propertyName` in the controller. Guards can't forward on data otherwise, they only return a boolean. This is how middleware have worked in node for a very long time